I'm trying to install the command tracepath but I get an error "Unable to locate package tracepath"
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package tracepath

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

The package name is iputils-tracepath (which can be found in the package archive by searching for "tracepath"), so install with:
sudo apt install iputils-tracepath


I already did and this is what it says
( sudo apt install iputils-tracepath
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
iputils-tracepath is already the newest version (3:20211215-1).
iputils-tracepath set to manually installed. )

Then it is installed, you can run the command tracepath then.

I did but there's no outcome

@AkiraCelosa all of this new information needed to be in your original Question above. This is an excellent and appropriate answer to the question that you actually asked.

@AkiraCelosa Also please explain exactly what you mean by "no outcome". No output at all? As if you didn't run a command at all? That seems very weird, I'd expect at least an error message, in any case please clarify this, adding to your question also the relevant output (if any)
